# python ignores environmet proxy settings

Tags: python

I am currently using python to write some appium test. Because I am behind a corporate firewall my traffic needs to go via a proxy.

I have set my http_proxy and https_proxy variables, but it seems like this is not being picked up by python during execution.

I tried the exact same test using javascript and node and the proxy get picked up and everything works so I am sure the problem is python not following the proxy settings.

How can I make sure python is using correct proxy settings?

I am using python 2.7 on macos mojave

Thanks!

Comment: what modules do you mean? As I know `requests` uses these variables but other modules doesn't have to respect them. Probably there is no settings in Python and all may depend on module's author.

Comment: I used the python appium client and javascript appium client for automated testing. The javascript version adheres the environment proxy settings. I hoped python will do the same, but I guess I am out of luck then as the author of appium explicitly say they have not support for the use of proxy.

I hoped there was a way to tell python to use environment proxy for all traffic or maybe some systemwide redirect through proxy.

Comment: maybe you check source code for python appium client. Maybe there is option for proxy.

Comment: Yes, trying to look into it now. It seems some parent module they override had some support for proxy so need to find that. Still very strange that it cannot be set on python level. java, c#, javascript etc. all use the environment http_proxy automatically.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out that appium currently does not support options to provide a proxy when making a remote connection. As temporary solution I modified the remote_connection module of selenium that appium inherits forcing it to use a proxy url for the connection.

My python knowledge is not that good but I think it shoudnt take much effort for someone to make a module that wraps/override the appium webdriver remote connection to include a proxy option.